# sweave not including blank lines in code output

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, sweave

I am trying to print out my code in sweave, along with the output.  I have found that when I try to print a big chunk of code, it removes the blank lines that separate it out.  I want to keep the spaces because I think it makes it easier to read.  Would love some suggestions!

```
Sweave Document chunk
<<echo=TRUE, results=tex, strip.white=FALSE>>=
 y = 2 + 2

 purple = 5+8

 cats = dogs 

@
```

Output:

> y=2+2
>   purple = 5+8
>   cats = dogs

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve what you want. One would be to add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\AtBeginEnvironment{alltt}{\doublespacing}
```

before your `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Same result :/.  I don't necessarily want it double spaced, but I do want the spaces I manually put into my code.

Comment: Maybe you could say something about your setup. Are you using Sweave or new knitr?

Comment: I am using sweave.

Comment: I am not sure if theres a difference concerning your problem, but could you try to compile using knitr? (RStudio -> Global Options -> Sweave -> Select Knitr)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I believe that @MartinSchmelzer is probably right. In RStudio (my current preview version is 1.3.926), navigate to Tools > Options... > Sweave, then select Weave Rnw files using: **knitr**.

[image: options]

Here's a minimal reproducible example that can then be compiled as PDF:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo=TRUE, strip.white=FALSE>>=
y = 2 + 2

purple = 5+8

cats = dogs 
@

\end{document}
```

The final PDF looks like this (note that `dogs` is not defined):

[image: output]

Comment: Just a note to say that the checkbox to prevent cleaning auxiliary output is found under Tools > *Global* options > Sweave. (This is for RStudio 1.3.959 on Win 10).